# How to combine all number input in a single row to a new output with all input combined?

Tags: batch-file

For example when I make the code like this:

`set/p input=>`

Then what's the formula if I make the input 1234 and the output will be 10? (The input's in a single row.)

Or summary, input : 1234 in a single row, and output will be 10 as combined from 1+2+3+4

thanks before!

edited: 
Wondering if there's any way to combine them all in a simplest way.

```
 set/p "input1=Input number 1 >"
 set/p "input2=Input number 2 >"
 set/p "input3=Input number 3 >"
 set/p "input4=Input number 4 >"
 set x=+
 set/a "output0"=input1%x%input2%x%input3%x%input4
 echo+
 echo Result : %output0%
```

nvm I got it.

```
goto main0

:main0
set x=+
set/p "input1=Input number>"
set in1=%input1:~0,1%
set in2=%input1:~1,1%
set in3=%input1:~2,1%
set in4=%input1:~3,1%
set/a "output0"=in1%x%in2%x%in3%x%in4
echo+
echo Result : %output0%
pause>nul
```

for 4 numbers. Thanks for making myself figuring out :)

Comment: I tried making several inputs based on the number that I want to make (8 digits) (just like copying all variable to input1, input2, and so on) but I knew that entering each single number in a different input will just wasting time for input and entering around 8 times, so I think I wanna combine all 8 input numbers to a single line and combine them all in that line. But I don't know the formula for that.

Comment: there is no formula. you'll have to come up with an algorithm, that's what programmers are paid for.

Comment: sorry for my English xD can't catch the difference between them (formula and algo).